# Why do I have so many /etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new.xxxx files?

Tags: debian, dhcp, dhclient

I don't understand why I have on one machine (debian 9) so many /etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new.xxxx files

### my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

### `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

### /etc/resolv.conf

```
#lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
----i---------e---- /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new.xxx` are the temporary files the DHCP client daemon writes before moving the complete file to `/etc/resolv.conf`. It is a measure to keep the consistency of the actual `/etc/resolv.conf` file if something goes wrong.

Something is happening that the DHCP client is not able to write the `/etc/resolv.conf` file/is dying, and the temporary files keep behind.

Answer to the OP: If somehow you are seeing several of those temporary files, you can delete them, the most it can happen if you delete a file that is being generated in the moment, is that it will a new one will be fetched again. The process is supposed to be quite fast, and *normally* you do not see those files [for long].

Addenda: The duplicate/temporary files are indeed being created because, as it can be seen with the `i` in the `lsattr` output, setting the immutable flag, you prevented all users, including root, from overwriting your `etc/resolv.conf` file.

To revert the situation, run:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Thx, how do I know when I can delete them?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Many Thx! do I have to report a bug report if I have still every DHCPrequest a new file created? how can I trace the source of these files creation?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out that the questioner had followed one of the many guides that tell people to make `/etc/resolv.conf` immutable.

Comment: @JdeBP Thought about that too.

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud Bug reports are not meant to be (ab)used for end user support. I would only open a bug report *if* I have debugged well the problem, and can prove the developers there is an actual bug. sysdig is one of the ways of trying to trace that activity, or strace. I would advise researching it, and if that fails, opening another question about it.

Comment: What is the output of lsattr /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro question updated

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro maybe part of the answer is that, on my machine `/etc/resolv.conf` is a static file and on the other workings ones, it is a symlink `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`

Comment: Could be,someone  might have fixed such lack of symlink with that static file. I do not allow neither network manager nor resolvconf packages in a server environment just to be on control.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` solved my case! I'm really thankful!

Comment: Good news, congrats.

Comment: @JdeBP Because `dhclient` is so anonying, people tried and failed to stop it from overwriting `etc/resolv.conf`, so made the file immutable as the last hand. I am one of them.